# symlink(): Could not fetch file information (error 2)

Tags: php, apache, iis, symlink, iis-express

I am trying to create symlink  in php with following code:

```
    $link = (session_save_path() ? session_save_path() : sys_get_temp_dir()) . "/sess_" . $this->generateSessionId($_REQUEST['broker'], $_REQUEST['token']);

    if (!file_exists($link)) $attached = symlink('sess_' . session_id(), $link);
                
    if (!$attached) trigger_error("Failed to attach; Symlink wasn't created.".$link, E_USER_ERROR);
```

I am using domain name instead of `localhost`. I tried to run this code on

Windows 7 with Apache, and Windows 8 with IIS / IIS Express / Apache

Everytime I get same error in logs as follows:

```
symlink(): Could not fetch file information(error 2)
```

It would be great if someone can help me out in this, I already spent whole night on this thing.

Comment: Does the note from Calin at http://us1.php.net/symlink help?

Comment: I checked this url before also, but it didn't helped me in any way. I am providing full absolute path, but still it isn't working.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally I found the problem.

I don't know how this code has worked for me before.

But now I checked the full path of file. It was simply session save path was different than temporary files path. So I used same session path in both links and it worked for me.

Still Thank you guys to provide me help about it.